# Accessing objects between components/controllers in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to share some objects between controllers in Angularjs and I have made something that works, but it just feels a bit clumsy to me. I'm wondering if what I have is acceptable, or if there's a preferred way to do so.

In componentA I have an object that I want to access from componentB.

```
app.component("componentA", {
    controller: function ($scope, $rootScope, $compile) {

        //the object whose contents I want
        $scope.objectToAccess = {name: 'object', value: 3};

        //receives broadcast from componentB, returns the object
        $rootScope.$on("getObject", function () {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('receiveObject', $scope.objectToAccess);
        });
    }
}

app.component("componentB", {
    controller: function ($scope, $rootScope, $compile) {

        $scope.object = {name : null, value: null};

        //receives the broadcast of the object and sets the value
        $rootScope.$on("receiveObject", function (event,object) {
            console.log(object);
            $scope.object = object;
        });

        //broadcast to get the object contents
        $rootScope.$broadcast('getObject');   
    }
}
```

This works, but it just feels too complicated with a lot of back and forth communication. Is there anything built into Angular that is specifically designed to handle this kind of thing, or is what I have considered acceptable?

Comment: I think what your doing(broadcasts) is the correct way to communicate between controllers.

Comment: Hmm from the example, it's hard to tell what the relationship of `componentA` and `componentB` is. Are they sibling components? If so, then consider creating a parent component, and those two could listen for `$onChange` events and react accordingly. What you have written will work but replacing `$broadcast` where possible is desirable.

Comment: another thing you can do, is to put the objectToaccess  in rootScope like
$rootScope.objectToaccess ={name: 'object', value: 3}
and then you can use it in any controller by just refering as $rootScope.objectToaccess .

But it is not recommended as it will globalize your object. so best way to do this is by creating a service which will have this objectToaccess object and then passing/injecting the service as dependency in the controllers where you want to access the objectToaccess.

Comment: @PushpendraPal I didn't realize that was possible with `$rootScope`. I think that actually might best fit my situation, even better than having a service. To be fair, I might be speaking prematurely as I've only briefly read about services and have to do some more research before deciding what is best for my situation.

Comment: @mcranston18 the object's contents can change, but it will be initially set and most likely won't change. I'd say they're more like siblings than anything. Could you give any good `$onChange` references for me to read about? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion $scope events should be used in cases where data changes are subscribed and not requested.

Instead you can use a service that will hold data and refer it in the controllers. Since services are singleton both the controllers will share the same instance and hence can easily share data.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I'm still pretty new to Angular so I'm not very familiar with services. Could possibly provide a tutorial or some sources that I can relate to for my current situation? I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this plunk [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/2t2zec8GHHoTc9zy4DnO?p=preview). Data entered in the inputbox will be shared between the components/controllers.

Comment: Would I have to create a "parent" controller for this?

Comment: considering this allows you to change the object from either of the controllers, is there any benefit of doing this over just using $rootScope?

Comment: The services approach does not need parent controller since it does not use scope. IMO, services are better for sharing of data and use scope events to notify occurrence of a change.